# vuetufy how to make image adjust to v-flex container?

Tags: thumbnails, vuetify.js

I'm starting to use Vuetify now and have a lot of question. One of the most bordering me now is I've found one image container "v-card-media" with two settings. By the fault, it clips image weight and keeps image height, and with "contain" option it doesn't but it anyway restrict the height of the container.

Is there a way to use images in a way as Foundation's thumbnail do? I don't know how to explain but I want to keep image fully visible and be placed in the frame of v-flex container.

Edited:
There are two examples in a comment below.

Comment: There are two examples I've made to illustrate the question. The Vuetify https://codepen.io/Arredatore/pen/QaBraO and the Foundation https://codepen.io/Arredatore/pen/bajMZY so what I'm looking for is an analogue of thumbnails in Foundation for Vuetify.

Answer (score 1):

So, for those who may be interested in. I just use the code of the thumbnail class from the Foundation and that works with v-flex pretty well.